# How to deal with multi class classification with SVM?

Tags: machine-learning, svm

I don't understand how to deal with multi class classification with SVM. All I have found at internet is one to all approach which is for binary classification only. But, my target is for example:

```
print(target)
```

Output:

```
[ 0  0  0 ... 9 9 9]
```

So, How to deal this with SVM properly? I have just build the model like those examples. But, it seems to me that's not correct way for multi label classification. Please guide me. If SVM is not a good choice at all, suggest me please which one will be good (and easy to implement like my example below if possible) among Random Forest, decision trees, K nearest neighbors etc. (except NN and CNN as I have already implemented with those two algorithms in my dataset, I just need one more algorithm to compare my results). So far, My coding:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(data, target, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

from sklearn.svm import SVC
model_svm = SVC(kernel='linear')
clf_svm = model_svm.fit(X_train,y_train)
y_svm = model_svm.predict(X_test)

from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
print('Accuracy of SVM: ', accuracy_score(y_svm, y_test))
```

Comment: Please clarify if you are actually talking about *multi-label* (a sample can belong to more than one classes simultaneously) or simple multi-class (many classes, but a sample can belong to one and only one class) classification.

Comment: multi-class, for example Fashion-MNIST; I have edited title of my question

Comment: What exactly you ask is unclear; do you have any specific issues with the code shown here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have used linear kernel, which is good only for linear boundaries:

```
model_svm = SVC(kernel='linear')
```

Try using, `rbf` that can be used for mostly non linear boundaries and very efficient.

```
model_svm = SVC(kernel='rbf')
```

reference: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_svm_kernels.html

Comment: What exactly for? Please bear in mind that OP has not actually reported any *specific* issue with their existing approach (at least not yet - requested to do so in the comments).

Comment: Just a basic question, is fashion-mnist linear or non-linear boundary?

Comment: yes, it is having non linear boundaries.looking at the fashion MNIST data it looks like that.

Comment: How exactly you define "looking"? Although the answer is most probably correct (in the sense of anything is more likely to be non-elephant than an elephant), the question itself is not so "basic" @user1896653 That's why I have insisted of what *exactly* is your issue here.

Comment: So, for multi-class classification problem, if we want to deal with SVM, we should use Polynomial or RBF instead of linear kernel, right?

Comment: sorry for my stupid question @desertnaut, I became confused unfortunately.

Comment: @user1896653 No - the "should" part is not correct here. There is no reason *in principle* why one cannot use a linear kernel for multi-class problems.

Comment: @desertnaut, I never mention in principal that we can not use linear kernel for multi-class problem. I have checked the data, according to me, 'rbf' would fit better than 'linear'

Comment: I was replying to @user1896653 wording here